# Understanding of how enclosures work in functions

Tags: rust

How does closure in `iter().map(|x| <anything to do with x>)` works, that it is taking every array elements and making new array

Comment: Is your confusion more on how closures work? or how `.map()` works?

Comment: This question is too open. Can you try showing some concrete behavior, some concrete program and its output, and what you were expecting instead? Then maybe this question can be answered. Btw, `map` is not making a new array.